# Call a java class directly from javascript without <APPLET> or <OBJECT>

Tags: javascript, java, dom-events

I've had *some* experience with Java and Javascript and searching this forum has helped me tremendously, but haven't been able to find this exact problem explicitly.  In a nutshell:  I want to call a java class straight from Javascript i.e. use a Java class in Javascript without OBJECT or APPLET.

Here's what what I'm experimenting with:

```
function screenSize() {
alert("Screen Dimension\n" + "  width:"
     + java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width
     + " height:" + java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
}
```

which is an example given on http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html.  This is hooked to a button on a page.  When clicking the button I (in essence) get:

> A Runtime Error has occured at line 35: 'java' is undefined.

I'm assuming that my path is incorrect or missing and there's a PATH or CLASSPATH or something I've overlooked.

I'd eventually like to move the javascript into a bookmarklet so that the user will be able to click a favorite on the appropriate page and have **magic** happen because of my own java classes manipulating the data from the screen.  For various reasons political and technical, I'm stuck using IE6-7 and have to work with scraping the web page in the browser and processing it on the client -- no sever side action for me!  I can assume that a JRE 6 will be available.

Is it a path issue?  Is what I want even possible and if so, how?  And how will packages work with all this?

Any advice or examples will be muchly appreciated.

Comment: what is the purpose of calling Java class?? Is it only to obtain the screen dimension??

Comment: Seems difficult to call java class without applet atleast. find out an alternative to this.

Comment: Sunil, The screen dimension is just an example I'm trying to get to work.  What I want to do is scrape the web page source (I can do that), pass it to a java class, which will use other classes to to process the page source.  Overall, simplified, I want to take a list of numbers from a web page, merge it with another list of numbers in a spread sheet and generate the merge list.
I've got the merge and spreadsheet stuff down, just need to get the source of the web page.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is running the Java Script in some kind of Java browser that has JavaScript support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tip shown at Real's HowTo used to work, but doesn't anymore.  Insert an applet and define public methods to interact with.

Comment: I'm wondering if I should mod your and jdigital's reply down as it isn't an answer, or mod you up because obviously it can't be done.

Comment: I thought you were the OP - which makes most of that comment I made, irrelevant. (shrugs) Whatever.

Answer (score 1):

In the link you referenced, did you notice this information at the top?

> On IE4 or better, you can't call java.* methods directly from Javascript or Jscript.

It goes on to explain that an Applet is needed.  Of course, IE4 is rather old, not sure how much of this is still relevant.  Good luck!